# How can I use "docker run --user" but with root priviliges

Tags: docker, permissions, sudo, mount

I have a Docker image which contains an analysis pipeline. To run this pipeline, I need to provide input data and I want to keep the outputs. This pipeline must be able to be run by other users than myself, on their own laptops.

Briefly, my root (/) folder structure is as follows:

```
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 May 29 15:38 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  1 17:09 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root  360 Jun  1 15:31 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 Jun  1 15:31 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  1 17:09 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 May 29 15:49 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 Mar 12 19:38 opt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 Jun  1 15:24 pipeline
dr-xr-xr-x 615 root   root    0 Jun  1 15:31 proc
drwx------   1 root   root 4096 Mar 12 19:38 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 May 29 15:38 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root   root    0 Apr 29 10:14 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root   root 4096 Jun  1 15:25 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root 4096 Feb 24 00:00 var
```

The pipeline scripts are in /**pipeline** and are packaged into the image with a "COPY. /pipeline" instruction in my Dockerfile.

For various reasons, this pipeline (which is a legacy pipeline) is set up so that the input data must be in a folder such **/pipeline/project**. To run my pipeline, I use:

```
docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/pipeline/project --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" pipelineimage:v1
```

In other words, I mount a folder with the data to /pipeline/project. I found I needed to use the --user to insure the output files would have the correct permissions - i.e. I would have read/write/exec access on my host computer after the container exits.

**The pipeline runs but I have one issue**: one particular software used by the pipeline automatically tries to produce (and I can't change that) 1 folder in $HOME (so / - which I showed above) and 1 folder in my WORKDIR (which I have set up in my Dockerfile to be /pipeline). These attempts fails, and I'm guessing it's because I am not running the pipeline as root. But I need to use --user to make sure my outputs have the correct permissions - i.e. that I don't require sudo rights to read these outputs etc.

My question is: how am I meant to handle this? It seems that by using --user, I have the correct permissions set for the mounted folder (/pipeline/projects) where many output files are successfully made, no problems there. But how can I ensure the other 2 folders are correctly made outside of that mount?

I have tried the following but not success:

- Doing "COPY -chown myhostuid:mygroupid" . pipeline/". This works but I have to hardcode my uid and gid so that won't work if another colleague tries to run the image.
- Adding a new user with sudo rights and making it run the image: "RUN useradd -r newuser -g sudo" (I also tried using the "root" group but no success). This just gives me outputs which require sudo rights to read/write/exec. Which is not what I want.

Am I missing something? I don't understand why it's "easy" to handle permissions for a mounted folder but so much harder for the other folders in a container. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software doesn't rely on relative paths (`~/`, `./`), you can just set `$HOME` and `WORKDIR` to a directory that any user can write:

```
ENV HOME=/tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
```

If you can't do that, you can pass the uid/gid via the environment to an entrypoint script running as root, chown/chmod as necessary, then drop privileges to run the pipeline (`runuser`, `su`, `sudo`, `setuidgid`).

For example (untested):

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -v "RUN_UID" ]] || { echo "unset RUN_UID" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ -v "RUN_GID" ]] || { echo "unset RUN_GID" >&2; exit 1; }

# chown, chmod, set env, etc.
chown $RUN_UID:$RUN_GID "/path/that/requires/write/permissions"
export HOME=/tmp

# Run the pipeline as a non-root user.
sudo -E -u "#$RUN_UID" -g "#$RUN_GID" /path/to/pipeline
```

**Dockerfile**

```
...
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Finally, pass the user and group IDs via the environment when running:

`docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/pipeline/project -e RUN_UID=$(id -u) -e RUN_GID=$(id -g) pipelineimage:v1`

Comment: I tried use the ENV and WORKDIR trick and almost got it working but it doesn't work entirely: for various reasons, my pipeline cannot be run with WORKDIR as the mounted folder. So I still have permissions issues: in other words, the only folder where I can freely make files and folders is the mounted folder but I cannot use that as WORKDIR. I have to do something like chown and chmod but the only way I managed to use it is with ""COPY -chown myhostuid:mygroupid"" where I have to hard code my uid and gid. I am not entirely sure  what you mean by entrypoint script, could you give an example?

Comment: @m93 I added an example for you to adapt.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!